# How to get version differences between a tag and the latest code in a branch?

Tags: git, jenkins

We need to validate if a particular file is being used by the development team for other user stories. So every time a developer finishes his changes, he will check the code and create a Tag. now the RM team will checkout the code based on this tag from the branch and need to compare with the latest version of the files in that branch to see if any files are changed post the creation of tag. So how do we compare file versions between a tag and the latest code in the branch.

Any help is highly appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: do `git diff tag latest_branch` or if you prefer to see the diff in a gui tool then configure diff.tool and do `git difftool tag latest_branch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `git diff` command can be used to compare any two versions, not just the `HEAD` and working tree.

In this case, if you want the changes between the tag `<tag>` and the branch `<branch>`, you can run `git diff <tag> <branch>`. If you only want a list of which files changed, you can add the `--name-only` parameter.